# Split rows of a dataframe according to time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

I have a pandas dataframe `df` that looks like the following:

```
df
Out[16]: 
  Start     End Value Start Realtime End Realtime Duration
0     0    2999     1         736051       736051    59.98
1  3000  104999     0         736051       736051  5639.98
```

For each row, I would need to check the `Start Realtime` and `End Realtime` column and if they are across one day (eg. `Start Realtime[0] = 29-05-2016 22:30:00` and `End Realtime[0]=30=05-2006 01:00:00` I should split the row in 2:

one from  `Start Realtime = 29-05-2016 22:30:00` until `End Realtime = 29-05-2016 23:59:59`

and

one from  `Start Realtime = 30-05-2016 00:00:00` until `End Realtime = 30-05-2016 01:00:00`

keeping the same value in the `Value` column and recalculating the duration (in seconds) and `start` and `end` columns (in samples)

It would be nice if I can keep the cut off time (in this example midnight) flexible..

Answer (score 0):

Just take it row by row for starters. The idea is if you have a row you need to split, then return a dataframe with two rows; otherwise return a dataframe with one. And then append it on to the new dataframe you are creating.

```
expanded_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i, row in df.iterrows():
        expanded_df = expanded_df.append(applyFunc(row), ignore_index=True)
```

For each row, create a cutoff time datetime object that is the closest to the start_time but after it. Then just see whether it falls between the start_time and end_time. Finally if it requires a split, create two new pandas series to return with the changed values.

```
def applyFunc(row):
        start_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(row["Start Realtime"])
        end_time = # Similar to above

        custom_hour = 11
        # custom_minute = ...

        cutoff_time = # Start with datetime.datetime(start_time.year, start_time.month, start_time.day, custom_hour, 0, 0) and see how you need to adjust with datetime.timedelta(...)

        if start_time < cutoff_time < end_time:
                before_cutoff = # Logic for before_cutoff; you will probably find row.set_value("key", value) useful
                after_cutoff = # Logic for after_cutoff series
                return pd.DataFrame([before_cutoff,after_cutoff])
        else:
                return row
```